# how to get number of row with a condition

Tags: mysql

i have a table like this

```
id   student teacher
10       a       b
11       c       b
12       d       c
13       e       b
```

student "e" is 3th student whose teacher is "b".
how to get this with one query?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT @row := @row + 1 as row, t.* FROM student_table t, (SELECT @row := 0) r where t.teacher ='b'
) s where student = 'e'
```

Answer (score 1):

Very close to post from Secator

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT (@row := @row + 1) AS rank, student
    FROM my_table,
    (SELECT @row := 0) q
    WHERE teacher = 'b'
) s
WHERE student = 'e'
```

Comment: This will return all students for teacher 'b', not just the third one.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't understand that way from the OP. Updated.

Comment: I believe if you run the above query in a PHP mysql query, it should return a row with 2 values: '3' and 'e'. If you need a more dynamic query you can use prepared statement to place 'b' as the teacher clause and 'e' as the student clause